# Menu button 2.3 and 4.0

Tags: android, menu, compatibility

Application must be run on 2.3 and 4.0.
On activity there are options menu.
On 2.3 - all ok present menu button on device.
On 4.0 - no menu button, an no way show option menu.
in manifest

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

activity

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_auth, menu);
  return true;
}
```

Q: 
How write application for run on 2.3 and 4.0, and using options menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's huge pain in making app compatible with older versions. There's one library I will suggest you to use. It damn good written by Jake Wharton called **ActionBarSherlock**. You can find out more here at the [link](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

I myself used in two apps till now. It allows you to use `ActionBar` (introduced in 3.0) in older versions like 2.2. It extends [android support-library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) There are themes provided in library and if set your app simple transforms into 4.0 in terms of look and feel.

Answer (score 3):

> How write application for run on 2.3 and 4.0, and using options menu?

Besides what you have already done, you need to have an action bar on API Level 11+, which will have a three-dots affordance to display the overflow menu (where all your options menu items will go that you have not put into the action bar itself). You should have an action bar by default given your existing android:targetSdkVersion="15".

For devices that have an off-screen MENU button, though, you will not see the three-dots affordance in the action bar. Instead, the user will need to press the MENU button to display your menu, just as they do on Android 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Lower your `targetSdk` to 10 (or lower)to legacy menu button to reappear.

And I strongly suggest you read this article [Say Goodbye to menu button](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) to undestand all the logic behind...

Comment: I dont think targetSdk 10 is the best solution. If anything it ruins the experience. Having that silly button on the screen instead.

Comment: I am telling OP what he may need to do if he wants old behavior restored without modifying his code if he want to go that way. Discussion on that is pointless I think - it's up to OP.